# Do I need to protect fd in multi-threaded read call?

Tags: linux, kernel, locking, pthreads, pipe

Does `read` system call implies a synchronization on the descriptor inside the kernel? I've seen some code use just a `read` call to synchronize and coordinate between multiple consumer threads, like this:

```
rfd,wfd = pipe() or socketpair(); // setup fd

// a single writer:
write(wfd, ...);

// multiple read threads, each blocks on read:
read(rfd, work);   // my questions is here
// do the work assigned by writer
```

while I used to think that a explicit lock like `pthread_mutex` has to be used, like this:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock;
// work threads:
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
read(rfd, work);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
// do work
```

So my question is whether an explicit lock necessary in this situation? Does `read` call guarantee proper thread safety in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe for multiple threads to call `read()` on the same file descriptor at once, but the `read()` call does not synchronize memory (it is not listed in [the functions specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12) to do so).

This means that it is only safe to rely on just the `read()` if you transfer all information required over the file descriptor itself.  If you want to use shared memory, you also need a memory synchronisation function - you don't have to hold the lock over the `read()` though, it would be safe to have a pattern like:

```
/* writer */

pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
/* ...write to shared memory... */
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
write(wfd, ...);

/* readers */

read(rfd, ...);
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
/* ... read from shared memory ... */
```

However, this would be quite odd, because if you are using shared memory and mutexes, you might as well use part of the shared memory and a condition variable to implement the signalling from writer to reader, instead of involving file descriptors.

Comment: Yeah, shared memory is one way. I'm more concerned about read/write here. So read/write on same fd will never result interleaved/incomplete result? like one thread got half of the data, and another got another half?

Comment: @fluter: It depends on the type of file descriptor.  For `socketpair()`, if you use a `SOCK_DGRAM` socket type then each successful `write()` will be a single datagram which must be sent and received as a unit.  For `pipe()`, if you write no more than `PIPE_BUF` bytes at a time, it is guaranteed to be atomic.  `SOCK_STREAM` sockets provide no guarantee.

Comment: Is that means for `SOCK_STREAM` socket one has to use `mutex` on multithreaded `read`s, as my example in question?

Comment: @fluter: That won't even help because you would have to actually loop around with the lock held until you are sure you have received the whole message, which might take multiple `read()` calls with a `SOCK_STREAM` socket.  And then you might run into the problem where you read the start of the *following* message as well.  `SOCK_STREAM` just isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: So what is the right paradigm in dealing with this situation?

Comment: Use a `SOCK_DGRAM` socket.

Comment: but `SOCK_DGRAM` is not reliable, I need reliable connection provided by stream sockets.

Comment: @fluter on linux, an AF_UNIX/SOCK_DGRAM socket is reliable, you can also use an AF_UNIX/SOCK_SEQPACKET which is also reliable, and connection oriented.

Comment: `AF_UNIX` domain `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets *are* reliable, and `AF_UNIX` is the only domain you can portably create with `socketpair()` anyway.